# Android:updating toolbar menu item on recyclerview item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, menuitem, android-menu

I am using `recyclerview` in my app. Initially there will be no menu items in toolbar but when an item from `recyclerview` is clicked a menu item should appear in `toolbar` .The item in the toolbar represents selected item.
To achieve this i have done something like this : Initially i have kept the selected item menu invisible and when `recyclerview` item is clicked ,make the menu item visible and new activity is opened.on `BackPress` of new Activity i open the previous activity again via intent so that menu item changes will take place in previous activity.If the previous activity is not opened via intent the menu item is not visible.On simple  backpress it will just return to the previous activity but not update it.
This is working fine but then i need to manage lot of back navigations manually and even the position of `recyclerview` item and lot more so is there any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: please put code here ,whatever  you tried ....